# Update with SubQuery from same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

Is it possible to update using a subquery from the same table?

I get this error:

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'tasks' for update in FROM clause

```
update tasks SET completed_form = 'y' AND all_forms_in = 'y' where EID in (select EID from tasks WHERE completed_form = 'y' AND all_forms_in = 'n' group by EID having count(*) > 1);
```

## UPDATE

I found that if I wrapped the query in another select it worked.  As referenced here: [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

```
update tasks SET all_forms_in = 'y' where EID in (SELECT * FROM (select EID from tasks WHERE completed_form = 'y' AND all_forms_in = 'n' group by EID having count(*) > 1)AS b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports JOIN in UPDATE statements, so you could do this without subqueries. You'd have to join to two distinct rows with your completed criteria to simulate the count(*) > 1.

```
UPDATE tasks AS t1
INNER JOIN tasks AS t2
  ON (t1.EID = t2.EID AND t2.completed_form = 'y' AND t2.all_forms_in = 'n')
INNER JOIN tasks AS t3
  ON (t1.EID = t3.EID AND t3.completed_form = 'y' AND t3.all_forms_in = 'n'
  AND t2.primary_key <> t3.primary_key)
SET t1.completed_form = 'y', 
    t1.all_forms_in = 'y';
```